# Star field won't appear, Can this be because of my Graphic Card

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, graphic, vga

I am working in a WebGL project with THREE.js, and in this project I have to make an Solar system.

But there is only a problem, the Star Field won't show up in the screen.... I tried many codes that I could find in the internet, i went through the steps of an tutorial, but still didn't work. I also downloaded the code of a starfield, but still the starfield won't appear!!.

I wanted to ask you, could the problem be my VGA (graphic card) ?? Here are the specification of my Graphic Card:

Chip Type: Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family
DAC Type: Internal
Adapter String: Mobile Intel (R) GMA 4500MHD
Bios Information: Intel Video BIOS

Total Available Graphic Memory: 797 MB
Dedicated Video Memory: 64MB
System Video Memory: 0MB
Shared System Memory: 733 MB

Everything that has to do with a star field won't appear on the screen, all other things like sphere, cubes, torus, texture mapping etc, are working fine, only the star field isn't!!

Comment: Do you think maybe it's an error in your code?

Comment: I don't think it's an error, if it would be, it wouldn't show me the other object that I have created... also why hasn't the code worked that I downloaded ... i mean the star field that i have downloaded...

Comment: An error would cause it to stop what it's doing, but if it's already done with the other objects then they won't just disappear. Check your error console.

Comment: i am working on sublime text.... it doesn't have an error console :(

Comment: You really need to show some code, how you are trying to create the star field. jsfiddle.net example would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show a picture, but often starfields can seem to vanish or turn black, if they are strongly filtered. Try using a different, nonsense picture for the starfield, and see if it appears.

The reason: the texture is scaled down. So if you have a 1-pixel bright 0xFF star in an area of, say, 16x16 pixels, when those pixels are filtered down the resultant brightness will only be 0x01

workaround: use a smaller texture, or an unfiltered one